# EXC_BAD_ACCESS within call to CGPDFContextClose

Tags: objective-c, ipad, exception, pdf, cgpdf

My iPad app encounters an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` message within the call to `CGPDFContextClose` in the following method.  It happens only for certain pages, and only for one document so far (which happens to be our help document, unfortunately).

```
- (CGPDFDocumentRef)newSinglePageDocumentFromDocument:(CGPDFDocumentRef)document page:(NSInteger)pageNumber
{
    CGPDFDocumentRef sourceDocument = CGPDFDocumentRetain(document);
    CGPDFDocumentRef newDocument = NULL;

    CFMutableDataRef consumerData = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    CGDataConsumerRef contextConsumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData(consumerData);

    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(sourceDocument, pageNumber);
    const CGRect mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFCropBox);
    CGContextRef ctx = CGPDFContextCreate(contextConsumer, &mediaBox, NULL);

    if (ctx)
    {
        if (page)
        {
            CGPDFContextBeginPage(ctx, NULL);
            CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page);
            CGPDFContextEndPage(ctx);
        }
        //EXC_BAD_ACCESS thrown here
        CGPDFContextClose(ctx);
        CGContextRelease(ctx);

        CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)consumerData);
        newDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);
        CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    }
    CGDataConsumerRelease(contextConsumer);
    CFRelease(consumerData);
    CGPDFDocumentRelease(sourceDocument);

    return newDocument;
}
```

The document which fails can be opened by Preview on the Mac.  I can't visually identify anything distinct between the pages that fail and the ones that succeed.

Can anyone see what is wrong with the code, or suggestions for uncovering the issue?

EDIT:
EXC_BAD_ACCESS is thrown within the CGPDFContextClose method, see below:

```
0x00e93d0e  <+0000>  push   %ebp
0x00e93d0f  <+0001>  mov    %esp,%ebp
0x00e93d11  <+0003>  sub    $0x18,%esp
0x00e93d14  <+0006>  call   0xe93d19 <CGPDFContextClose+11>
0x00e93d19  <+0011>  pop    %eax
0x00e93d1a  <+0012>  mov    0x8(%ebp),%ecx
0x00e93d1d  <+0015>  test   %ecx,%ecx
0x00e93d1f  <+0017>  je     0xe93d30 <CGPDFContextClose+34>
0x00e93d21  <+0019>  cmpl   $0x43545854,0x8(%ecx)
0x00e93d28  <+0026>  jne    0xe93d30 <CGPDFContextClose+34>
0x00e93d2a  <+0028>  cmpl   $0x1,0x10(%ecx)
0x00e93d2e  <+0032>  je     0xe93d4e <CGPDFContextClose+64>
0x00e93d30  <+0034>  mov    %ecx,0x8(%esp)
0x00e93d34  <+0038>  lea    0xc393b(%eax),%ecx
0x00e93d3a  <+0044>  mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x00e93d3e  <+0048>  lea    0xad9eb(%eax),%ecx
0x00e93d44  <+0054>  mov    %ecx,(%esp)
0x00e93d47  <+0057>  call   0xe7176c <CGPostError>
0x00e93d4c  <+0062>  jmp    0xe93d59 <CGPDFContextClose+75>
0x00e93d4e  <+0064>  mov    0x18(%ecx),%eax
0x00e93d51  <+0067>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x00e93d54  <+0070>  call   0xdb25af <CGContextDelegateFinalize>
0x00e93d59  <+0075>  add    $0x18,%esp //EXC_BAD_ACCESS thrown here
0x00e93d5c  <+0078>  pop    %ebp
0x00e93d5d  <+0079>  ret
```

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. I can confirm that this issue is related to iOS 5. I do not have the same issue in iOS 4. It seems to be related to embedding a font from the previous PDF into the new PDF.

Comment: I recommend filing a bug report http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=1441402

Comment: @rebelzach, Thanks.  I've added extra notes to the existing bug report.

Comment: Also filed a bug report with Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up submitting a bug to Apple (ID 10555351) and removing the caching functionality.

Comment: Hey Robert, did anything ever come out of the Apple Bug filing?

Comment: @PhilippeSabourin, it was eventually closed as a duplicate of 10428451 which was at the time scheduled to be investigated.  I'm not sure how to check the status of that bug.

Comment: We've been hitting a lot of these apple bugs for rendering PDFs, hopefully they take a look at them all soon.

Comment: Also reported a similar crash under radar ID 15317874 including some sample data that causes the crash.

Answer (score 3):

Set [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), [MallocStackLogging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging), and [guard malloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) in the debugger.  Then, when your App crashes, type this in the gdb console:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x543216
```

Replace `0x543216` with the address of the object that caused the crash, and you will get a much more useful stack trace and it should help you pinpoint the exact line in your code that is causing the problem.

[See this article for more detailed instructions.](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone)

---

One thing to also do is to set "Strip Debug Symbols" to "No" so that if you test on your device, you will be able to read crash logs:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: If the source of the exception is within library code, will turning on these options show me any useful information?

Comment: For those using Xcode 4, all three of these options are now available as check boxes: edit your scheme, select Run from the left-hand list, select the Diagnostics tab, check the ones you want.

Comment: @RobertGowland If it's your library and you have the source for it, then this should show you a useful stack trace even in that library.  One thing to also do is to set "Strip Debug Symbols" to "No".  Check my updates.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  The exception is thrown within CGPDF code, so I can only see the assembly.  See my edit.